# Wrong result outputted

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am writing a code that will output "Nice work!" if the entered GPA is over 3.5 and "you need to study harder if the entered GPA is under 2.0. But it is not outputting correctly.

```
if(gpa[i] >= 2.0){
printf("You need to study harder! \n");
}
else if(gpa[i] <= 3.5){
printf("Nice work! \n");
}
```

I expect the output "nice work!" if the gpa is over 3.5.
and "you need to study harder" if the gpa is under 2.0.

Comment: `>=` reads as "greater or equal". I like to think of the open end of the `<` or `>` as the larger end ... so, when `a > b` ... it means `a` (closest to the open end) is larger than `b`.

Comment: What does the debugger show as the value of gpa[i] before the first if-statement

Answer (score 1):

You confused with the logical operator within if condition.
It should be like

```
if(gpa[i] <= 2.0){
    printf("You need to study harder! \n");
}
else if(gpa[i] >= 3.5){
    printf("Nice work! \n");
}
```